# jquery hyperlink characteristics

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

In the following code why is that on click of details the page zoom shifts to top of the page and how can this be prevented

```
 <a href='#' onclick='javascript:toggle(%s);'>Details</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;%s %s <b>Total Sal: </b>%s<br><div id='%s' style='display:none;'>%s</div><br>"%(divname,first_name,lastname,usage,divname,html_table)
```

Note: the above code is generated on the server side..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you href to

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `return false` at the end of onclick event which will prevent the default action.

```
 <a href='#' onclick='javascript:toggle(%s); return false;'>Details</a>
```

Since you are using jQuery this is not the way you call functions in jQuery. Use [**unobtrusive way of coding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). Something like

```
$("#anch").click(function(){
    // your code for click event
    // $("#togg") will get the div element wrapped as a jQuery object
    return false;
});

<a href='#' id="anch">Details</a>
<div id="togg"></div>
```

*Note*

You id seems to be invalid.

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a
>   letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed
>   by any number of letters, digits
>   ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores
>   ("_"), colons (":"), and periods
>   (".").

[**Read more**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)